# Read/Write Microsoft Access (.accdb) synced to Sharepoint with Ruby

Tags: ruby, ms-access, sharepoint

I have had success with reading and writing to my Microsoft Access .accdb database using Ruby, and a local Access database.

Unfortunately I need to be able to do this to a database that has been uploaded to and is synced via Sharepoint.

Is it possible to do this?
how is the username/password handled?

Any advice or sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Marc, the 'database' is a .accdb, as stated in the first line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding your situation, so I apologize in advance if that is the case.

When you sync an Access DB with SharePoint, Access creates a SharePoint list for each table. It then links the list to the local Access database. As you edit data through your forms, you are actually editing the data in the SharePoint list. Access serves as a proxy, and each list in SharePoint is surfaced as a linked table in Access, along with a connection string which caches the credentials. You could continue to work with the Access table (which is actually now a SharePoint list), or bypass Access altogether and work with the list in SharePoint directly. SharePoint has an API and other techniques that allow you to work with the list programmatically. If that is your scenario, you no longer need to use Access. Ruby can just work with SharePoint.

Let me know if this is off track, and perhaps I can still help.

Comment: I will pursue the SharePoint API. It does make total sense now that you point it out. Much appreciated, I'll let you know how I go